# Put div elements next to each other and center them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to put 5 div elements next to each other and also center them. However, I cant make it work. Here is my code

```
<div style="width:200px;margin-right:20px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default text-center" style="border: 1px solid #fab05d;border-radius:0px;">
     <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#fab05d;color:#ffffff !important;border-radius:0px;">
        <h1>2017</h1>
        <p style="line-height: 14pt; margin-top:3px;margin-right:25px;">EARLY BIRD*</p>
        <p style="clear:both;line-height: 16pt;">GOLD PACKAGE <br>REGISTRATION**</p>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:5px;">
        <p style="color:#929393;font-size:15px;"><strong>$x.00 TICKET</strong></p>

        <div style="display:inline-block;margin:auto;padding-top:1px;margin-top:1px;" class="text-center">
        <input type="image" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/gold_remove.png" id="gold_r" style="">
        <input type="text"  class="text-center" id='goldval' name="quantity" size="5" onchange="gold_change()" style="vertical-align:top;font-weight:bold;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #929393;">
        <input type="image" src="http://localhost" id="gold_a" style="">

        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have **5** of them. They are basically the same, only the content is different. All 5 divs are inside **container-fluid** (I am using bootsrap). I have tried to add **display:inline-block** to my container but it doesn't work. Also, I used **float:left** but in that case, I can't properly align my divs when the screen size changes. I tried to use the extended version of Bootstrap grid when you can create equal 5 columns but in that case, my div's content gets messed up. Can anyone please give me some solution that will work for all screen sizes? Thanks

Comment: I cannot see 5 sibling div in the provided markup . Please provide complete html

Comment: @RahulB I tried to add the full code but for some reason system renders part of it. It is basically container which contains 5 of these div blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a larger screen, I think this will work. The snippet's screen is very small that's why it does not align together. Use Media Queries to adjust the `div`'s size so that it can accommodate smaller screen size

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid red;" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid red;" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid red;" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid red;" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid red;" class="col-xs-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```css
.col-xs-2{
    background:green;
    color:#FFF;
}
.col-half-offset{
    margin-left:4.166666667%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="p1">One</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p2">Two</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p3">Three</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p4">Four</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p5">Five</div>
        <div>lorem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```